# List all class objects

Tags: c#, list

I'm wanting to list all class objects in sort of a list. I have created a bunch of objects with the 'new' tag. It's easier to show you in code so here it is.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    releaseitem trk1 = new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 01", "2014");
    releaseitem trk2 = new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 02", "2016");
    releaseitem trk3 = new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 03", "2012");
    releaseitem trk4 = new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 04", "2011");

    Console.WriteLine("ID\t\t\tArtist\t\tTitle\t\t\tRelease Year");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    trk1.getDetails();
    trk2.getDetails();
    trk3.getDetails();
    trk4.getDetails();
}
```

You see, at the moment, I have to get the details of each song individually and it shows up like this:

[image]

However, I'm soon going to make it so the user can input their own data, and I want to make it so that when the user types "List All", it shows all of the tracks, in a fashion shown in the screenshot. I'll show you what's in the releaseitem class, but I'm not sure if I'll have to change anything there:

```
public class releaseitem
{
    private string artist = "";
    private string title = "";
    private string releaseyear = "";
    private string id = "";

    public releaseitem(string artist, string title, string releaseyear)
    {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
        this.releaseyear = releaseyear;
        idTracker.nextId += 1;
        id = "REL-" + (idTracker.nextId).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
    }

    public void getDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}", id, artist, title, releaseyear);
    }
}
```

Ignore the use of 'private', I have no idea on the difference of public and private yet haha.

Comment: I won't say more than [C# List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a List to keep a list of classes (or any number of different collections).

To do so, you could do something like this:

```
List<releaseitem> myList = new List<releaseitem>()
{
   new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 01", "2014"),
   new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 02", "2016"),
   new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 03", "2012"),
   new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 04", "2011")
};

foreach (releaseitem item in myList)
    item.getDelails();
```

You would of course need a UI of some sort, or at least a way to add new items to your list, but that could look like:

```
releaseitem newReleaseItem = new releaseItem("entered artist", "track number", "year");
myList.Add(newReleaseItem);
```

also note, you should keep data types as similar to their data as possible, like `year` should probably be an `int`, if not an actual `datetime` for the release date that you could extract the year from.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the class `List<T>` which you can use like this:

```
releaseitem trk1 = new releaseitem("ARTIST", "TRACK 01", "2014");

var list = new List<releaseitem>();
list.Add(trk1);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.getDetails();
}
```

Use `list.Add` to add more items to the list; the `foreach`-loop will output all of the items you stored so far.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Gonna add the ability for a user to add their own data now!